# Считать текст метки с одного контроллера в другом контроллере

Tags: xcode, ios

Задавал полчаса назад подобный вопрос, но так и не разобрался.
Может меня немного не так поняли, задам немного другой вопрос по содержанию.

У меня есть два контроллера (привязанные к двум разным представления). На первом стоит метка с нейким текстом. Мне нужно на втором контроллере считать текст метки с первого контроллера.

Допустим, я создал выход для метки, прописал синтезайз для создания сеттеров и геттеров.

Как на втором контроллере произвести считывание текста с метки первого контроллера?

Вот сам проект http://dfiles.ru/files/e74ppu5ex

Comment: Для начала контроллеры должны быть между собой как-то связаны - как вы это делаете?

Comment: Ко второму контроллеру добавляю #import "ViewController.h". ViewController - первый контроллер

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дмитрий, ваш код заработает, если вы немного дополните его:

В вашем Storyboard, для ViewController найдите поле Storyboard ID и сделайте его равным *ViewControllerID*, затем подправьте свой код для *viewDidLoad*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

ViewController *obj1 = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID"];

    [obj1 view];

    NSLog(@"%@",obj1.label1Outlet.text); //Сюда по идее должно вывести значение метки, которая в первом представлении, т.е. Denis. Но выводит null. Я перевробовал много вариантов о которых писали, но так и не получилось. // Теперь выводит!
```

}

Теперь комментарий:

Во-первых, просто строка **[[ViewController alloc] init]** создаёт экземпляр ViewController опираясь лишь на его декларацию в его файлах ViewController.h,.m - она никак не говорит Xcode/Objective-C, что вы хотите инициализировать ваш ViewController именно в том виде, в каком он представлен в Storyboard. Вместо этого вы должны прямо обратиться к соответствующей Storyboard (это делается с помощью *+[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:]*), которая и выдаст вам соответствующий ViewController с вашими outlets, в том виде, в каком вы "нарисовали" его в MainStoryboard - это делается следующей строкой, использующей -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:].

Во-вторых, как справедливо заметил [@1101_debian](/users/228/1101_debian) в вашем предыдущем вопросе: "Для того чтобы подгрузились данные из InterfaceBuilder'а вам достаточно просто дернуть вьюху" - я делаю для этого минимальный вызов *[obj1 view];*, который заставляет "вьюху" взять представление вашей label1Outlet из MainStoryboard.

Неясно, какую цель вы преследуете, но когда вы определитесь со схемой взаимодействия ваших контроллеров, то есть, реализуете, например, одну из следующих схем:

- Modal presentation, performSegueWithIdentifier...
- Parent-child, используя addChildViewController [Creating custom container view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers)
- Или может быть создадите parent-контроллер, который будет родителем для обоих ваших нынешних контроллеров, используя опять же addChildViewController

...вам естественно не нужно будет вручную "дергать вьюху", так как это будет происходить автоматически при использовании любого из этих или других подходов.

Comment: У меня так заработало.

Comment: Спасибо большон. Я только учусь и много еще не заню

Answer (score 0):

Кажется теперь более менее понятна проблема.
Одним из способов передать какой-либо объект из одного контроллера в другой - это написать кастомный инициализатор для второго контроллера. Например так:

```
 MyViewController *vc2 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithObject:myObject];
```

В качестве myObject может выступать значение из нужной метки.

Можно не писать кастомный инициализатор, а создать новое свойство для второго контроллера.
Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
 MyViewController *vc2 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
 vc2.newProperty = @"abc";
```

Вместо вышеприведенного текста можно считывать значение из метки.

Такой метод сработает в случае, если второй контроллер инициализируется непосредственно в первом (в таком случае в первом контроллере надо импортировать второй контроллер).

Если же задача сложнее и оба контроллера независимы друг от друга, то можно использовать статические переменные.. ну или сохранять в отдельном файле, или настройках.. В общем надо точнее знать, как планируется использовать эти данные.