# Переход между представлениями

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

```
Допустим я делаю игру для iOS. У меня есть меню и мне нужно при нажатиии на button организовать переход к другому представлению. (сейчас я это делаю через нажатия на ctrl и выбираю пункт modal, но переход осуществляется с анимацией).

Как можно сделать переход между представлениями (допустим в меню игры, где не используется навигационный контроллер и таб бар. желательно программно)? Я работаю в последней версии xcode.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способ:**

См. следующую секцию в [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/)

```
Presenting Another View Controller’s Content

    – presentViewController:animated:completion:
    – dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
      modalTransitionStyle  property
      modalPresentationStyle  property
      definesPresentationContext  property
      providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle  property
    – disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
    – dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: Deprecated in iOS 6.0
    – presentModalViewController:animated: Deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

То есть вам нужно сначала инициализировать контроллер, который вы хотите презентовать (как инициализировать контроллеры связанные со storyboard может помочь этот мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217638)), а потом вызвать, например, изнутри вашего исходного контроллера.

```
[self presentViewController:ControllerToBePresented animated:... completion:...];
```

**Ещё способ:**

Если подходят отношения родитель-ребёнок:

см. соотвествующую секцию в том же [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/)

```
Managing Child View Controllers in a Custom Container

      childViewControllers  property
    – addChildViewController:
    – removeFromParentViewController
    – shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods
    – shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods
    – transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:
    – beginAppearanceTransition:animated:
    – endAppearanceTransition
    – viewControllerForUnwindSegueAction:fromViewController:withSender:
    – segueForUnwindingToViewController:fromViewController:identifier:
    – automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers Deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

**Ещё способ:**

создавать в ваших Storyboards необходимые вам переходы (Segues) и инициализировать их програмно используя методы из опять же [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/)

```
Using a Storyboard

    – shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
    – performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
    – prepareForSegue:sender:
    storyboard  property
    – canPerformUnwindSegueAction:fromViewController:withSender:
```

Comment: спасибо. буду читать

Comment: Мне похоже нужно ещё некоторое время, чтобы собрать наглядные ссылки - слишком сурово получилось ;)

Comment: Всё отлично. опроповал первый способ, всё работает ( – presentViewController:animated:completion:)

Comment: Ну вот и чудесно!